# How to disable or change CakePHP standard Authentication autologout?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, logout

I have some problems with CakePHP 1.3 standard Authentication. It seems that users or admin users get log out too easily... especially on some browsers. In IE7-9 it sometimes needs only to change window or tab in browser to log out. This is annoying.

I have found that many users have these kind of problems but I'm unable to find good resources or examples how to specifically adjust automatic log out. I found out that some Security.level settings etc. might affect these, but tips are not very precise...

In user authentication, I would like to disable automatic log out or at least make a long timeout for active logged in user. Any advices or howto-guides how to change auto log out behaviour without changing the cake core (not intended anyway)...?

Answer (score 0):

use this code perhaps solved your problem,

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Enter', '/pages/home', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always had trouble with it, too. Just recently I started to use Miles' AutoLogin component which at least "cloaks" the problem:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/02/more-persistent-sessions-in-cake2-x/

Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, I have to check this out!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that if Security level is set to high in `core.php`, as in `Configure::write('Security.level', 'high');` my users get logged out very quickly if their Session times out without the timeframe set by the Security.level.

When I changed that to medium the problem went away.

Comment: I already had that in "medium" but now I changed also the "Session.checkAgent" to false. Let's see what users say. I guess that checking http agent -setting is ok to change...